# How to cancel a recurring payment with django-merchant?

Tags: django, payment, recurring

When i create a recurring payment object like that:

response = merchant.recurring(amount, credit_card)

how can I cancel it?? Someone can help me please?

Comment: We can help you but we do not know how if you provided so little information.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm using django-merchant in an app that has a membership section, so I need that when a user select some paid plan this plan is paid monthly, for that reason I use the recurring method of django-merchant, but I don't know how to cancel that if the user in some time decide to changes his paid plan for a free plan, please help me ....

Answer (score 1):

The docs for django-merchant are somewhat sparse, but from a look at [the page on Gateways](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-merchant/en/latest/gateways.html) (i.e. merchants), `merchant.void(whatever_the_recurring_transaction_id_was)` seems the most promising - it's described as voiding previously authorized transactions that were done with merchant.authorize(), so may do the same for recurring transactions.